# how i configuration mod_security?

Tags: configuration, mod-security

when i setup mod_security default configuration then if anyone go wordpress admin panel and change any code or some modified then his ip block. why? my all customer complain for this problem. how i can solve this. i want if anyone change anything from his wordpress then his ip not block only anyone want to try hack or give wrong password then his ip block how i can do it. how i can setup mod_security

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+mod_security

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box mod_security is very sensitive. All you can do is look at the modsecurity_audit.log or use [modgrep](http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2011/08/modsecurity-advanced-topic-of-the-week-audit-log-searching-with-modgrep.html) to gather the various log parts together and decide which rules to ignore which locations to whitelist.

You're in a world of irritation ...